# How to add line on the top of the text in excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, microsoft-excel-2016

How do I add horizontal line on text in excel 2016. It is like underline but it goes on the top instead of bottom of the text. There are explanations on the internet for earlier versions of excel but I can't find anything for excel 2016. I have been trying with formulas with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to write that requires an overline?

Comment: I'm doing it with single char, so "Combining Diacritical Marks" is doing the trick.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 ways? It's kind of convoluted, but here you go.

1. Use symbol insert: "Combining Diacritical Marks"
2. Use border, upper line, on a single cell.
3. ALT+ENTER to skip to new line in a single cell.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a way but this feels like there must be a better way! However, as you've not had an answer, and you do not explain how much text you need to update in this manner, I'll provide it.

Enter some text in a cell, click in the cell and type the letter `a`. Whilst the caret is to the right of this text go to the Insert ribbon and the last icon should be Symbol. Click on it

In the box called subset, choose Combining Diacritical Marks

Choose the symbol you want and it will combine! However, this appears to  only work character at a time!

Another option may be using a border and applying it to the top!

Or, if you're showing a maths formula and need the X with the line above, click on Symbol and choose the font MS Reference Sans Serif form within the Symbol dialog. Then type in F7C4 as the unicode number.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283669/write-text-with-overline

Another option is to search for a font which has this effect!

Another option is to use the line tool in insert ribbon and illustrations tab, see Shapes and then lines.

The issue you may have is that I don't believe Excel supports it. If you try to copy HTML and paste into Excel, the formatting persists. It persists for underline and strikeout, but not overline.

Answer (score 0):

search and replace within string use chr(10)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha-KCZcS5CI

Comment: If you could, please write how it's done just in case the video goes down.

Answer (score -1):

In Excel (V. 2002 I think) from MS Office 365, it is possible to add a bar on top of anything using the Equation feature.
The equation created can be freely placed anywhere in the sheet like an image.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBWjv.png)

Path:
Menu: Insert > Symbols: Equation > Structures: Accent > Accents: Bar